# combinatorial descents finding the number of permutations with criteria

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, descent

I need help with the following:

Define a descent of a permutation to be $j$ when $p_{j+1} < p_j$. Then the descent set of a permutation is the set of all descents. For example, the $5$-permutation:
\begin{equation}
4, 3, 1, 5, 2
\end{equation}

has descent set $D=\{1, 2, 4\}$

How many $9$-permutations have descent sets $D$ such that $D$ is a subset of $\{1,4,7\}$?

I cannot think of any way to enumerate a result so I started thinking of inclusion exclusion, however I feel like this approach is the same in terms of complexity because finding the descent sets that are not subsets is just as hard. By complexity I mean figuring it out.

**EDIT**
I am looking for a concrete answer now. For example, say we have $2$-descents between elements $1$ and $2$ and elements $5$ and $6$. A solution I have seen says that the quantity given by ${8 \choose 1}\cdot{7\choose 4}\cdot {3\choose 3}$ tells us the number of subsets with descent set $=\{1 5\}$. That is the two descents happen between indices $1$ and $2$ and $5$ and $6$.

What does the quantity mean though? I see we are "choosing" numbers between the indices of the descents but I still cannot piece enough reasoning together to convince myself that this is correct. I am now multiplying these numbers together because I do see that these steps are independent.

Thanks, and all help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5):

It's the same as asking for the number of permutations with $$p_2\lt p_3\lt p_4,\quad p_5\lt p_6\lt p_7,\quad{\rm and}\quad p_8\lt p_9$$ So, given a random permutation, what is the probability of $p_2\lt p_3\lt p_4$? Is it independent of the probability of $p_5\lt p_6\lt p_7$? and so on....

EDIT: There are $9!$ permutations of $1,\dots,9$. Pick any one of these, call it Joe. How many of the $9!$ agree with Joe except, possibly, at positions 2, 3, and 4? Well, that's the number of permutations of the numbers at those $3$ positions, so it's $3!$. Of those $3!$, how many have no descent at positions 2, 3, and 4? Only one, the one that has $p_2\lt p_3\lt p_4$. So, we have to divide the $9!$ total permutations by $3!$ to get the number with no descent at 2, 3, and 4. Similarly, we have to divide again by $3!$ to get the number with no descent at 5, 6, and 7, and by $2!$ to get the ones with no descent at 8 or 9. So we come up with $${9!\over3!3!2!}$$ This is basically the same reasoning as in Michael's answer, without using the vocabulary of group theory.

I don't see how to get the result in the comment for $9$-permutations with descent set $\{{1,5\}}$. I get $9!/(4!4!)=630$, where your formula gives $280$.

Comment: Can you give a more concrete explanation without probability? For example, say we have $2$-descents between elements $1$ and $2$ and elements $5$ and $6$. I solution I have seen says that the quantity given by ${8 \choose 1}\cdot{7\choose 4}\cdot {3\choose 3}$ tells us the number of subsets with descent set $=\{1 5\}$. That is the two descents happen between indices $1$ and $2$ and $5$ and $6$. What does the quantity mean though? I cannot piece enough reasoning together. I am multiplying these numbers together because I caught your independence reasoning.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a hint if you know some group theory:

Consider the subgroup $H = S_1 \times S_3 \times S_3 \times S_2$ that permutes the sets $\{1\}$, $\{2,3,4\}$, $\{5,6,7\}$ and $\{8,9\}$ individually (but elements of $H$ aren't allowed to send numbers from one of these sets to another).  Then $H$ acts on $S_9$ *on the right* and each coset in $S_9 / H$ has a unique representative whose descent set is contained in $D = \{1, 4, 7\}$.  (Why?  Remember that multiplying one permutation by another permutation on the right has the effect of shuffling the *positions* of the original permutation.)

Thus, the number of permutations you seek is equal to the number of cosets in $S_9 / H$, so it equals $|S_9| / |H| = 9! / (3! 3! 2!) = 5040$.

Comment: This leads to the same numbers as my answer of 17 Feb, but I wonder if we aren't both wrong. Let's take permutations of $\{{1,2,3,4,5\}}$ with descent set $\{{3\}}$. I think our reasoning gives $5!/(2!3!)=10$, but I only find $9$; 12435, 12534, 13425, 13524, 14523, 23415, 23514, 24513, 34512.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: I believe the question asked for the descent set to be a subset of $D$ (= $\{3\}$ in your example).  So the missing permutation is the identity $12345$. :)  If you want exactly a specific descent set $D$, I think you might be stuck relying on inclusion-exclusion.

Comment: You're right --- I missed the word "subset". Good, that probably means my answer was OK, too.